# qBittorrent to CIFS share strange write spikes

Tags: nfs, cifs, proxmox

This will probably get deleted, but I don't know how to write this without going on for paragraphs.

I am having huge trouble trying to get qBittorrent to play nice with my new NAS (Synology DS1511+)

My setup is that I have an old box running Proxmox, with all of the Arrs, qBittorrent, and Plex in their own LXCs. qBittorrent was downloading to a  locally connected drive with no issues, I have since added a NAS and everything works fine over NFS, except for qBittorrent, it hammers the NAS I think trying to preallocate space. I noticed using qBittorrent to DL to the NAS from windows worked fine. So my next step was to try SMP on the Proxmox server.

These are my notes from testing

```
LAN IO goes haywire when qBitorrenting over NFS v4.1
But not when "Preallocate disk" is off?
NFS v4.2 supports preallocation but is not yet supported by Synology
Gonna try SMB
DLing with qBittorent on Windows to the NAS connected via SMB (M:/), LAN IO is as expected
File transfer through the linux server to the NAS (WinSCP), LAN IO is as expected
Whereas SMB3 on linux server, qBittorrent to the NAS, there is a baseline LAN out of the NAS (1-3MBps) and the LAN in spikes
Resulting in a DL speed of 90% normal (windows case)
Drive write also follows these spikes ... increased drive wear?
```

I know that a logical thing to do is to use qBittorent on the NAS itself, and am currently setting that up to test. But its a last resort as I would like to keep thing set up as they are on the Proxmox server (looking to add usenet in the future, again i know that could be on the NAS)

What are my next steps in testing? I'm out of ideas as to what varibles to change and i would like to solve the current issue of the write spikes.

Thanks